# Restrict user access

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, access

I have a list on SP online which has a bunch of members. Currently, the members can add, edit and delete rows in this list.

However, the current purpose is to restrict users to deleting only the rows enetered by them.

Please note that the rows have `username` column that contains the memeber's username associated with their Microsoft account. So, I was thinking maybe this column can be used to create such access restriction.

How can I do this?

Comment: User should be able to delete the items added by other users?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, no user should be able to delete their own items only

Comment: But can they delete the items for others?

Comment: How current permissions are set for the list? Are you using group for members or you granted permissions for individual users? It will be difficult to remove delete permissions for only one user if all users (including the person in username column) are part of the single group And other user should be able to delete the items for `username`.

Comment: @GaneshSanap no a user can't delete items for another user's items. Yes, current permissions are using group for members.

Comment: If no group members should delete any list items, you can try creating custom permission level without delete permissions and use it instead of "Contribute" or "Edit" permissions as mentioned below by @user79408.

Comment: @GaneshSanap, if it's not much can you kindly explain this in an answer?

Comment: Sorry but I also want them to be able to delete there items i.e. items entered by them. Hence, a user will not be able to delete items entered by other users.

Comment: I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below approach for your requirements:

1. Remove Delete permissions on list for all users

- Create a new permissions level "Contribute without Delete" by copying the "Contribute" permission level and removing "Delete Items" and "Delete Versions" options from the List Permissions.
- Follow this article: [How to Set Permissions to add but not delete in SharePoint?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/02/sharepoint-online-permissions-to-add-but-not-delete.html)
- Use this permission level to grant permissions to group members on the SharePoint list instead of default permission levels

2. Allow person in "username" column to delete their items:

- Create a power automate flow on item creation (and/or item update - as per you requirements).
- Break permissions inheritance on list item
- Grant Contribute or Edit permissions (as per your requirements) to user email mentioned in "username" column
- Also grant permissions to site owners/admins for safer side

Follow below links for breaking permissions:

1. [Power Automate - Break Inheritance And Set List Item-Level Permissions In SharePoint Online](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/power-automate-break-inheritance-and-set-list-item-level-permissions-in-sharep/)
2. [Stop sharing an item or a file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#stop-sharing-an-item-or-a-file)

Follow below links for granting permissions:

1. [Grant access to an item or a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#grant-access-to-an-item-or-a-folder)
2. [Setting SharePoint Permissions with Power Automate](https://steveknutson.blog/2021/12/10/setting-sharepoint-permissions-with-power-automate/)

Comment: Thank you so much, for step `Create a power automate flow on item creation (and/or item update - as per you requirements).` Can you please expand on this or maybe share a link which shows this process?

Comment: If the person in "username" column will be set only when item is created (Or if you are using SharePoint default "Created By" column), you can use [when an item is created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-an-item-is-created). Check the trigger used in this article for example: https://365hq.net/break-and-change-list-item-permission-using-power-automate/

Answer (score 2):

To prevent users deleting items, you would probably need to [create a custom permission level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels) that doesn't have the delete privilege and apply that to the members of the list instead of the current Edit permission level. I'd recommend copying the `Contribute` permission level and unselecting `Delete Items` from the List Permissions.

You'd then need to create a Power Automate flow that [grants Edit access to the individual list item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/manage-list-item-file-permissions) for the `Created By` user.