# How to setup permission group, to delete content created by that user only, but able to modify other users content

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, flow, groups, sharepoint-permissions

I am working on requirement that requires new permission group to be setup in such a way:

1. Members of that group should be able to delete only self created
   data
2. Members of that group should be able to edit self and others created data

I have tried creating custom permission group, but there is no option for deletion as per my requirement, can someone please help me out on this.

Note: I am using SharePoint online

Comment: I think you will need item level permissions for your list. on item creation, use power automate flow to break permission inheritance and then grant current user **Edit/Full Control** permissions and **Contribute** permissions to SharePoint group.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding there is not OOTB way to configure permission according to your first requirement.

As workaround you can change permission of item/file after creating it using Power Automate. For your first requirement you don't need to create any group but for second requirement you can create one SharePoint Group e.g. Group 2

From Power Automate you can set below permission:

- Created By (User Work Created Item) - Contribute
- Group 2 - Contribute

Please find below article which can help you to setup permission once Item is added to list:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-experience-sharing-permissions
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Je15hs8IqA

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box permissions.

You need item level permissions for your list.

on item creation, use power automate flow to break permission inheritance and then grant current user **Edit/Full Control** permissions and **Contribute** permissions to SharePoint group.

Check my answer here for setting up the Power automate flow: [Restrict user access](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304393/restrict-user-access/304413#304413)